# feedback on navigation with multiple level of hierarchy

Tags: navigation, responsive

I am designing a responsive website with 3 levels of hierarchy. I wanted to get some opinions and feedback on the following navigation.[image]

Level 1 contains a list of body systems ex: cardiovascular
Level 2 contains type of view ex: Xray, standard
Level 3 contains list of organs ex: ventricle
Level 4 is the details page.

Comment: What's the purpose of the app? Is it simply educational or for professionals to record something? Some background would help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to give an answer to a non specific question. But I try to give some thoughts.

- Is there a reason why all levels look differently (level 1 entries in a list, level 2 in a grid, level 3 only text?
- Is there a reason why the label are below the icons (i suppose the black dots are icons)? This uses a lot of space and a user would have to scroll quit a lot to get to the desired entry
- Level 3: the links seem very close together which makes it difficult to tap on them.
- How does it behave. What I mean, what is the transition from one level to the other?
- how to I come back from level 3 to 2 or 1?

As said, your question is extremely broad, but these are the first things that popped in to my mind, looking at your mockups. If you do need more specific answers you should probably ask more specific questions about your design.

Comment: 1. Level 1 has ten systems, level 2 has four types and level 3 can have more than 100 organs. Thus the layout. 
2. I can fix that to be adjacent to the icon.
3. The wireframe is to explain the concept. Level 3 doesn't contain any images just a list of all the organs can be 100+. 
4. So once user taps on body system--> go to perspective view-->on selecting a perspective it goes to organs list-->then to details
5. You can come back using the mobile back button or browser back ( as this is a responsive website)

I would appreciate if you can suggest any approach to improve this experience